# Ionic4:"ionic cordova build ios "not working

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic4

After changing some changes in html and ts those are not redirecting into ios xcodeproj when building my app by using ionic cordova build ios

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
ionic doctor

ionic repair
```

Or maybe just removing and readding the platform:

```
ionic cordova platform remove ios

ionic cordova platform add ios
```